# Passing variable from php to bash script doesn't work

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to execute a bash script, which have just the task to delete some lines by sed command, by passing the variable(lines in this case) from php.

php code:

```
$var1 = 2; 
$var2 = 4;
$var11 = escapeshellarg($var1);
$var22 = escapeshellarg($var2);
$output=shell_exec("dhcp.sh $var11 $var22 2>&1");
```

bash code:

```
line=$1 
line2=$2 
sed -i "${line},${line2} d" pippo.txt;
exit
```

If I try to execute bash script from shell without passing variable script (ex: line=1 line2=3) seems work fine but when I call it from php passing variable doesn't work.
I can't find solution at that simple problem. hope that someone can help me. Thnaks in advance.

ps: is there any possibility that is a permission problem?

Comment: `$output=shell_exec("sed -i ${var11},${var22} d pippo.txt");`  try it directly

Comment: what is the output ? Calling shell can produce errors permission (if script is not readable executable) or if not in current dir (when called ./) or not in PATH as called relatively

Comment: @AlivetoDie tryed but doesn't work too.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I dont really need an output, i just need to know if command works and lines have been deleted. However, files are in the same directory ad they have 755 permission with the same owner.

Comment: Try `\`dhcp.sh $var11 $var22 2>&1\`` in your php script instead of `shell_exec("dhcp.sh $var11 $var22 2>&1");`, by using backticks you can execute code directly instead of needing to use shell_exec, this will not fix the problem but it looks better and is a bit faster.

Comment: as you have `$output=sell_exec` and `2>&1` (errors are redirected to output), if you look at $output content it will help you to resolve your problem

Comment: @nusje2000 already tryed and doesn't work.

Comment: Read the output than as @NahuelFouilleul told you. If it refers to a permission problem try `sudo php path/to/php/script.php` or `chmod 777 path/to/bash.sh`.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul  I've already change permission to bash script to 777 and that's the output: sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedAftVq9: Permission denied .

Comment: seems php process is missing write permission (on pippo.txt or current directory) which is needed for `sed -i`

Comment: @nusje2000 with backticks directly from php I can't get neither the output.

Comment: It was just a permission problem. I've solved modifying sudoers file. Thank to all.
PS: have I to change post's title?

Comment: @gabriele.taibi: no, we don't use title hacks like [solved] here. A self-answer is encouraged though, if you think it would help others - see the "answer your own question" button.